# Getting "undefined error" for first time and after page refresh data getting displayed in react using redux

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

I am fetching data from an API using react-redux.

I am logging the user in and then after fetching an API when I visit the page it displays cannot read property map of undefined but then again if I reload the page the data gets displayed as expected.

This is my profile Action .js page

```
import profileAPI from "../../../API/ShopUserAPI/profileAPI";

export const PROFILE_LOAD = "PROFILE_LOAD"
export const PROFILE_FETCH = "PROFILE_FETCH"
export const PROFILE_ERROR = "PROFILE_ERROR"

export const getProfile = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: PROFILE_LOAD, payload: '' })
        profileAPI.get('/shop/details')
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp)
                dispatch({ type: PROFILE_FETCH, payload: resp.data.data })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                dispatch({ type: PROFILE_ERROR, payload: 'Error occured. Retry' })
        })
    }
}
```

profile reducer page

```
import { PROFILE_LOAD, PROFILE_FETCH, PROFILE_ERROR } from "../actions/profileActions";

const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
    profileData: [],
    profileError: ''
}

const profileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case PROFILE_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case PROFILE_FETCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                profileData: action.payload
            }
        case PROFILE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                profileError: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default profileReducer
```

Page where I have dispatched the action

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ShowProfile from "./ShowProfile";
import { getProfile } from "../../../store/ShopUserStore/actions/profileActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const Profile = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.getProfileData()
    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            <ShowProfile />
        </div>
    )
}

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getProfileData: () => dispatch(getProfile())
    }
  }

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile)
```

Page where I am accessing the state

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  Container, Typography, Grid, Button,
  Dialog, DialogActions, DialogTitle
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

  contentCenter: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },

  newSection: {
    marginTop: '1rem'
  },

  innerSection: {
    padding: '1rem'
  }

}));

const ShowProfile = (props) => {
  console.log(props.profileData)

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);



  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      < Container>
        {/* shopname heading */}
        {props.profileData.map((data, index) => (
          <Typography style={{ fontSize: "24px" }} key={index} className={classes.contentCenter}>
            {data.name}
          </Typography>
        ))}


        {/* shop profile details card */}
        <Grid className={clsx(classes.newSection, classes.contentCenter)}>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            {props.profileData.map((details, index) => (
              <Paper key={index} elevation={3} className={classes.innerSection}>
                <Typography >
                  Shop name : {details.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  Phone Number : {details.phone}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  Shop no : {details.shopNo}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  Complex : {details.complex}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  Landmark : {details.landmark}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  Street : {details.street}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  Area : {details.area}
                </Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.newSection}>
                  City : {details.city}
                </Typography>

                <Grid container justify="flex-end" className={classes.newSection}>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
                        Home
                  </Button>
                    </Link>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                      Edit
                  </Button>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        {/* Edit shop profile dialog*/}
        <Dialog onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title" open={open}>
          <DialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
            Edit shop profile
        </DialogTitle>

          <DialogActions>
            <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              Close
          </Button>
            <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              Save changes
          </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>

      </Container>
    </div >
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    profileData: state.profile.profileData
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShowProfile)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the "cannot read property map of undefined" error happening?

Comment: In the page where I am accessing the state which should contain the data which I have fetched from an API @RossAllen

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay but I am not getting any answers and I really need it . @halfer

Comment: What is the output of your console logs in your first code block, `console.log(resp)` and `console.log(err)`?

Comment: Initially when I visit that page console shows blank array like this `[]` then `undefined` 
and then when I refresh the page it shows blank array initially [] and below that it shows an array with data which is what it should be in first go.  @RossAllen

Comment: What about the `console.log` for the response from the API? `resp.data.data` is `undefined` on the first page load then I would expect to see the behavior you're describing.